# How to read XML into a class/classes that matches its xsd

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, xsd.exe

So I have an XSD and a webservice that delivers in that same format.

Now I could go ahead and read the xml into a document, create my objects from the class etc... But I am thinking, there must be some easier way to do that.

Am I right? ;)

- [Yahoo Maps GeocodeResponse XSD](http://api.local.yahoo.com/MapsService/V1/GeocodeResponse.xsd)
- [Yahoo Maps GeocodeResponse sample](http://local.yahooapis.com/MapsService/V1/geocode?appid=YD-9G7bey8_JXxQP6rxl.fBFGgCdNjoDMACQA--&street=One%20Microsoft%20way1&city=redmond&state=washington)

```
<ResultSet xsi:schemaLocation="urn:yahoo:maps http://api.local.yahoo.com/MapsService/V1/GeocodeResponse.xsd">
 <Result precision="address">
  <Latitude>47.643727</Latitude>
  <Longitude>-122.130474</Longitude>
  <Address>1 Microsoft Way, #Way1</Address>
  <City>Redmond</City>
  <State>WA</State>
  <Zip>98052-6399</Zip>
  <Country>US</Country>
 </Result>
</ResultSet>
```

Below are auto-generated classes (two actually), using [xsd.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87621/how-do-i-map-xml-to-c-objects)

[image: class diagram]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer_methods.aspx) to deserialize the XML text into instances of the classes generated by **xsd.exe**.
The XmlSerializer will use the **metadata attributes** placed on the generated classes to map back and forth between XML elements and objects.

```
string xmlSource = "<ResultSet><Result precision=\"address\"><Latitude>47.643727</Latitude></Result></ResultSet>";

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ResultSet));
ResultSet output;

using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlSource))
{
    output = (ResultSet)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a Typed DataSet from the XSD and then fill one of those objects with the XML. That's the pretty common method.

Comment: Interesting! How would you fill it?

Answer (score 0):

The [XSD Code Generator](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/XmlStudio/Xml-Data-Binder.aspx) in Liquid XML Studio does a great job of creating highly compliant c# or vb.net code from an XML Schema. This code can then be used to call or implement a web service.

If your implementing a web service then you can take control of the WSDL produced using XmlSchemaProvider and IXmlSerializable, see [Taking Control of your WSDL](http://xml-tricks-and-tips.blogspot.com/2009/01/take-control-of-your-wsdl.html)