# Generate C# class of .xsd file

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xsd.exe

I'm trying to generate a c# class out of a XML schema but with no success.

This is the command in `Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017`:

```
xsd invoiceApi.xsd /classes
```

Output:

```
c:\temp\test>xsd invoiceApi.xsd /classes
Microsoft (R)-Unterstützungshilfsprogramm für XML-Schemas oder Datentypen
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.6.1055.0]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:TaxpayerIdType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 1154, Position 8.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:SimpleText50NotBlankType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 1016, Position 8.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:TaxpayerIdType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 982, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:SimpleText1024NotBlankType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 956, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:SimpleText512NotBlankType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 930, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:CountryCodeType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 862, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:PostalCodeType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 868, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:SimpleText255NotBlankType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 874, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:SimpleText255NotBlankType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 880, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:SimpleText50NotBlankType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 886, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:SimpleText50NotBlankType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 892, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:SimpleText50NotBlankType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 898, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:SimpleText50NotBlankType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 904, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:SimpleText50NotBlankType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 910, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:SimpleText50NotBlankType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 916, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:SimpleText50NotBlankType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 812, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:SimpleText15NotBlankType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 824, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:SimpleText512NotBlankType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 830, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:SimpleText200NotBlankType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 836, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:CountryCodeType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 842, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:SimpleText50NotBlankType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 848, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:SimpleText50NotBlankType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 729, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:SimpleText1024NotBlankType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 735, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:LineNumberType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 741, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:SimpleText50NotBlankType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 709, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:InvoiceReferenceType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 669, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:TaxpayerIdType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 557, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:InvoiceCategoryType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 563, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:PaymentMethodType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 569, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:InvoiceAppearanceType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 575, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:CurrencyType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 599, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:MonetaryType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 605, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:MonetaryType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 611, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:MonetaryType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 617, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:MonetaryType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 623, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:SimpleText50NotBlankType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 456, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:SimpleText512NotBlankType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 462, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:SimpleText50NotBlankType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 430, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:SimpleText1024NotBlankType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 436, Position 5.
Schemavalidierungswarnung: Der Typ 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:TimestampType' ist nicht deklariert. Zeile 346, Position 5.

Warnung: Das Schema konnte nicht validiert werden. Die Klasse kann möglicherweise nicht generiert werden, oder es werden falsche Ergebnisse erstellt.

Fehler: Fehler beim Generieren der Klassen für das invoiceApi-Schema.
  - Der Datentyp 'http://schemas.nav.gov.hu/OSA/1.0/data:TimestampType' ist nicht vorhanden.
```

You can download the schema [here](https://onlineszamla-test.nav.gov.hu/api/files/container/download/OSA%20schemas.zip)

Comment: [Related?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060017/convert-xsd-files-to-c-sharp-serializable-class)

Comment: did you reference all related xsd-files also? Seems like at least one import could not be resolved.

Comment: I just downloaded the xsd file there and executed this command. how can I make a reference?

Comment: Add the names of all the referenced xsd files to the command-line, separated by space. Note that, if I recall correctly, the output will take the name of the last file mentioned.

Comment: i think that was the problem. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved using both files:

xsd invoiceData.xsd invoiceApi.xsd /classes