# Object Xml Mapping

Tags: spring.net

I knew that the Spring 3 has a feature of object xml mapping. But I can't find the corresponding feature in Spring.net 1.3.1.

Does this functionality exist in spring.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think object xml mapping (OXM) functionality is present in Spring.net.

Note that Spring.net is not an exact port of Spring for Java - it's a ["spiritual port" rather than a quick port](http://www.springframework.net/overview.html).

For more information on mapping c# objects to xml, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87621/how-do-i-map-xml-to-c-objects) is a good starting point.

Comment: From [this article](http://guidoschmutz.wordpress.com/2010/01/06/testing-the-new-objectxml-mapping-support-of-spring-3-0-with-jibx-and-maven/) I understand that Spring OXM is now part of Spring core, but was originally in Spring web services. I know that Spring.net uses the .net xml-serializer for its web service functionality and not a custom mapper.