# Custom SQL Queries and SubSonic ActiveRecord?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, activerecord, subsonic

I'm needing to do some SQL queries manually because ActiveRecord doesn't support any kind of XPath query.

I'd love if I could somehow send in a query and it give me back a list of data objects. What would be the easiest way to do this without manually loading each column into an object's property

Answer (score 1):

SubSonic has a "CodingHorror" class which enables me to do inline queries and it has a method `ExecuteTypedList<T>()`. So I'm going to try loading things that way and see how it works

Answer (score -1):

So you need to load xml into c# objects?
Sounds like this maybe...

[How do I map XML to C# objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87621/how-do-i-map-xml-to-c-objects)

Comment: No, I need to query my database using XPath(only in the where clause) and load the result into standard SubSonic objects.