# Deserialize an object graph with private members in C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I want to deserialize an object graph in C#, the objects in the graph will have object and collection properties, some of the properties may be private, but I do not need to worry about cyclic object references. My intent is to use the deserialized object graph as test data as an application is being built, for this reason the objects need to be able to be deserialized from the XML prior to any serialization. I would like it to be as easy as possible to freely edit the XML to vary the objects that are constructed. I want the deserialization process not to require nested loops or nested Linq to SQL statements for each tier in the object graph.

I found the DataContractSerializer lacking. It can indeed deserialize to private fields and properties with a private setter but it appears to be incredibly brittle with regard to the processing of the XML input. All it takes is for an element in the XML to be not in quite the right order and it fails. What's more the order it expects the data to be declared in does not necessarily match the order the object members are declared in the class declaration, making it impossible to determine what XML will work without having the data in the objects to start with so that you can serialize it and check what it expects.

The XmlSerializer does not appear to be able to serialize to non-public data of any type.

Since the purpose is to generate test input data for what might be quite simple applications during development I'd rather not have to resort to heavyweight ORM technologies like Entity or Nhibernate.

Is there a simple solution?

[Update]
@Chuck Savage

Thanks very much for your reply. I'm responding in this edit due to the comment character limit.

In the technique you suggested the logic to deserialize each tier of the object hierarchy is maintained in each class, so in a sense you do have nested Linq to SQL just spread out across the various classes involved. This technique also maintains a reference to the XElement from which each object gets its values in each class, so in that sense it isn't so much deserialized as just creating a wrapper around the XML. In the scenario I have in mind I'd ideally like to be deserializing the actual business objects the application will use so an XML wrapper type object like this wouldn't work very well since it would require a distinctly different implementation for test usage compared to production usage.

What I'm really after is something that can do something akin to what the XmlSerializer can do, but which can also deserialize private fields, (or at least properties with no setter). The reason being that the XmlSerializer does what it does with minimal impact on the 'normal' production use of the classes involved (and hence no impact on their implementation).

Comment: Just a thought. using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) you can mark your private properties with `JsonProperty` to include in serialized data.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10158569/353147

You will have to create your own boilerplate code to go back and forth to xml, but with the included extensions that can be minimized.

Here is another example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9035905/353147

You can also search my answers on the topic with: `user:353147 XElement` in the StackOverflow search.