# Convert generic XML List to C# object

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I have this XML file format (coming from a third party API):

```
<root>
    <parameter name="id">189880</parameter>
    <parameter name="target">2c92c0f83ff55b4b014007d6194e1bed</parameter>
    <parameter name="account">2c92c0f93fd531f1013feed6c1095259</parameter>
    <parameter name="contact">Laurie</parameter>
</root>
```

This file can contains between 1 and 50 lines describing a different property for each line.

I want to dynamically convert it to a C# object. Each line of the file will become a property and be populated by the corresponding value.

Example based on the XML above:

```
public class Result
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string target { get; set; }
    public string account { get; set; }
    public string contact { get; set; }
}
```

Edit :

Let's simplify the problem. Let's assume that the file structure is fixed (for example always the 4 lines attributes described above )

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I map XML to C# objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87621/how-do-i-map-xml-to-c-sharp-objects)

Comment: There is no such thing as "dynamically convert to a [strongly typed] C# object" (at least not strongly typed above the DOM/Tree level). Kirill's approach will save some manually creation of DTO/annotation classes, which could be handy. Once there *is* a DTO/annotation class then something like XmlSerializer is easy to use.

Comment: And how you are going to use type, which you created dynamically? `var x = BuildSomethingFrom(xml); x.???`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Xsd.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) tool to generate C# class from XML. Then use `XmlSerializer` to deserialize  object.

Comment: I already managed to deserialize the XML object. But as the XML file can change from 1 to 50 lines I am not able to create dynamically the corresponding C# object

Comment: Thank you but It's not what I am looking for. Please check my question again (2nd part of it) I need a strongly typed object.
Maintaining the code using a Dictionnary will be a pain.

Comment: @Massanu, Therefore you have two options: generate class as I mentioned in my answer or create it manually.

Answer (score 1):

You are better off using a `Dictionary<T,T>` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx with key/value pairs, if the properties will be dynamically changing.

Comment: Thank you but It's not what I am looking for. Please check my question again (2nd part of it) I need a strongly typed object. Maintaining the code using a Dictionnary will be a pain.

Comment: Create a class with every possible property, then parse the XML, while checking every attribute if it's null or not, and appropriately setting them, based on the check.